# VPN not working in kitkat 4.4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, stock-android, connection-issues, vpn

I am using Lenovo A6000 running stock rooted Kitkat 4.4.4. And since about 6 months the vpn has stopped working properly. Everytime I connect to a VPN via mobile data, it connects and then gets disconnected after about 10 seconds and the 3G/4G icon vanishes too momentarily.As a result the VPN disconnects, rendering it useless.

I tried everything, different VPN apps, factory reset, wiped system, data, cache, dalvik cache, internal storage. Nothing fixed the problem.

This problem does not exist in 5.0+ android but i really don't want to update because anything other than stock Kitkat is buggy and drains battery heavily.

Anyone know how to fix this?